EasyMotion plugin doesn't load automatically on Vim startup in WSL Ubuntu
I am using Windows with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) running Ubuntu. In my Vim setup, I have the EasyMotion plugin installed. However, the plugin does not load automatically when I start Vim. I have to manually run :PlugUpdate each time to get it working.
Here is my .vimrc file:
" Disable compatibility with vi, required
set nocompatible

" Required for plugins
filetype off

" Set leader key
let mapleader = " "

" Initialize Vim-Plug
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Plugins
Plug 'mileszs/ack.vim'
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Plug 'haya14busa/incsearch.vim'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'FooSoft/vim-argwrap'
Plug 'jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator'
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plug 'haya14busa/incsearch.vim'
Plug 'haya14busa/incsearch-easymotion.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'  " 自动补全括号
Plug 'crusoexia/vim-monokai'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline' " 状态栏显示
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align' " 快速对齐

" Initialize Vim-Plug
call plug#end()

" Enable file type detection and plugins
filetype plugin indent on

" Syntax highlighting
syntax on

" CtrlP configuration
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'

" Syntax and indent
set showmatch " Show matching braces when text indicator is over them

" Highlight current line, but only in active window
augroup CursorLineOnlyInActiveWindow
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END

" 256 colors configuration
if has('gui_running')
    colorscheme monokai
    let g:lightline = {'colorscheme': 'monokai'}
elseif &t_Co < 256
    colorscheme monokai
    set nocursorline " Looks bad in this mode
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme monokai

" Basic editing config
set shortmess+=I " Disable startup message
set nu " Number lines
set rnu " Relative line numbering
set numberwidth=5
set virtualedit=onemore
set incsearch " Incremental search (as string is being typed)
set hls " Highlight search
set listchars=tab:>>,nbsp:~ " Set list to see tabs and non-breakable spaces
set lbr " Line break
set scrolloff=5 " Show lines above and below cursor (when possible)
set noshowmode " Hide mode
set laststatus=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start " Allow backspacing over everything
set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100 " Fix slow O inserts
set lazyredraw " Skip redrawing screen in some cases
set autochdir " Automatically set current directory to directory of last opened file
set hidden " Allow auto-hiding of edited buffers
set history=8192 " More history
set nojoinspaces " Suppress inserting two spaces between sentences
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set wildmode=longest,list
set wildmenu
set mouse+=a " Enable mouse mode (scrolling, selection, etc)
if &term =~ '^screen'
    set ttymouse=xterm2
endif
set nofoldenable " Disable folding by default

" Misc configurations
map <C-a> <Nop>
map <C-x> <Nop>
nmap Q <Nop>

set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=

set splitbelow
set splitright

nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>d :call ToggleMovementByDisplayLines()<CR>
function SetMovementByDisplayLines()
    noremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> k v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'
    noremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> j v:count ? 'j' : 'gj'
    noremap <buffer> 0 g0
    noremap <buffer> $ g$
endfunction
function ToggleMovementByDisplayLines()
    if !exists('b:movement_by_display_lines')
        let b:movement_by_display_lines = 0
    endif
    if b:movement_by_display_lines
        let b:movement_by_display_lines = 0
        silent! nunmap <buffer> k
        silent! nunmap <buffer> j
        silent! nunmap <buffer> 0
        silent! nunmap <buffer> $
    else
        let b:movement_by_display_lines = 1
        call SetMovementByDisplayLines()
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-n> :set rnu!<CR>

command -nargs=0 Sudow w !sudo tee % >/dev/null

" Plugin configuration
nnoremap <Leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>f :NERDTreeFind<CR>

let g:buffergator_suppress_keymaps = 1
nnoremap <Leader>b :BuffergatorToggle<CR>

nnoremap <Leader>u :GundoToggle<CR>
if has('python3')
    let g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1
endif

nnoremap ; :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
let g:ctrlp_switch_buffer = 0
let g:ctrlp_show_hidden = 1

command -nargs=+ Gag Gcd | Ack! <args>
nnoremap K :Gag "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>
if executable('ag')
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""'
    let g:ackprg = 'ag --vimgrep'
endif

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
    \ 'mode': 'passive',
    \ 'active_filetypes': [],
    \ 'passive_filetypes': []
\}
nnoremap <Leader>s :SyntasticCheck<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>r :SyntasticReset<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>i :SyntasticInfo<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>m :SyntasticToggleMode<CR>

nnoremap <Leader>w :ArgWrap<CR>

noremap <Leader>x :OverCommandLine<CR>

let g:markdown_fenced_languages = [
    \ 'asm',
    \ 'bash=sh',
    \ 'c',
    \ 'coffee',
    \ 'erb=eruby',
    \ 'javascript',
    \ 'json',
    \ 'perl',
    \ 'python',
    \ 'ruby',
    \ 'yaml',
    \ 'go',
    \ 'racket',
    \ 'haskell',
    \ 'rust',
\]
let g:markdown_syntax_conceal = 0
let g:markdown_folding = 1

set tags^=.git/tags;~

" Local customizations
let $LOCALFILE=expand("~/.vimrc_local")
if filereadable($LOCALFILE)
    source $LOCALFILE
endif

set laststatus=2
set statusline=%f\ %y\ %m
set statusline+=%{mode()}

let g:EasyMotion_do_mapping = 1
map <Leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
nmap <Leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
nmap s <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f2)
nmap ss <Plug>(easymotion-s2)
map <Leader>L <Plug>(easymotion-bd-jk)
nmap <Leader>L <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-line)
map <Leader>w <Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)
nmap <Leader>w <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-w)

autocmd cursorhold * set nohlsearch

noremap n :set hlsearch<cr>n
noremap N :set hlsearch<cr>N
noremap / :set hlsearch<cr>/
noremap ? :set hlsearch<cr>?
noremap * *:set hlsearch<cr>N
map z/ <Plug>(incsearch-easymotion-/)
map z? <Plug>(incsearch-easymotion-?)
map zg/ <Plug>(incsearch-easymotion-stay)


It will cause an error if I try to use some motions.

I am new to Linux and Vim, and find it quite difficult to deal with it.
Thanks in advance!

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

"I am new to Linux and Vim, and find it quite difficult to deal with it" - note that every plugin you install adds to the complexity. That's a whopping 16 plugins you dump on your Vim. My advice would be to learn the basics first and add plugins once you're comfortable with vanilla Vim.
